# How can I make a method into a generic where I pass in a class and a string?

Tags: c#

I have a method that I call like this:

```
    var Start = await cosmosManager.GetDocumentItemsForLogStartAsync();

    public async Task<List<LogStart>> GetDocumentItemsForLogStartAsync()
    {
        List<LogStart> Items2 = new List<LogStart>();
        try
        {
            collectionLink = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, collectionId);
            var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<LogStart>(collectionLink).Where(x => x.Activity == "Start").AsDocumentQuery();
            while (query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                var retrivedData2 = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<LogStart>();
                Items2.AddRange(retrivedData2);
            }
        }
        catch (DocumentClientException ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error: ", ex.Message);
        }
        return Items2;
    }
```

What I would like to be able to do is to call the method like this:

```
var Start = await cosmosManager.GetDocumentItemsForLogAsync(LogStart, "Start");
var Views = await cosmosManager.GetDocumentItemsForLogAsync(LogViews, "Views");
var Feedback = await cosmosManager.GetDocumentItemsForLogAsync(LogFeedback, "Feedback");
```

Where LogStart, LogViews and LogFeedback are all classes.

Is there a way I can change my method so this could work to avoid me having to create three different methods?

Comment: Have you tried using C# generics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use C# generics.

Also, in C# local variables should be `camelCased` not `PascalCased`.

I assume your `Where` clause is type-specific, which means you'll need to move that to a parameter. I assume this needs to be an `Expression<>` over a `Func<>` instead of just a pure `Func<>` (it depends if you're using `IQueryable<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`).

```
    public async Task<List<T> GetDocumentItemsAsync<T>( Expression<Func<T,Boolean>> predicate )
    {
        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        try
        {
            collectionLink = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, collectionId);
            var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(collectionLink)
                .Where( predicate )
                .AsDocumentQuery();

            while (query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                var retrivedData2 = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>();
                list.AddRange(retrivedData2);
            }
        }
        catch (DocumentClientException ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error: ", ex.Message);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Used like so:

```
var start = await cosmosManager.GetDocumentItemsAsync<LogStart>( x => x.Activity == "Start" );

var views = await cosmosManager.GetDocumentItemsAsync<LogViews>( x => x.Activity == "Views" );

var feedback = await cosmosManager.GetDocumentItemsAsync<LogFeedback>( x => x.Activity == "Feedback" );
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  I will try that out right away and get back to you.